# Sale of the product is done many times before the first purchaser acquires it!

Tags: investing, stock-markets, commodities

I'm a complete newbie, like I just searched how to make money trading stocks kinda newbie.

I read on a blog, "in the stock market, the product which is the subject of the deal is sold many times whilst still in the possession of the first seller and before the first purchaser acquires it."

I used to believe that you open an online account and then buy stocks of the companies or commodities that you believe that their prices will go up.

How can I buy and sell something that I haven't possessed yet? What does that quoted sentence referring to? I wanna understand.

Comment: It would be helpful to link to the blog in question so that we can see in what context that quote is used.  It doesn't obviously make sense out of context.

Comment: The quote appears to be from [Stock Short Selling](https://www.amjaonline.org/fatwa/en/82754/stock-short-selling) and [Ruling on dealing in petroleum and other commodities on the stock exchange](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/124311/ruling-on-dealing-in-petroleum-and-other-commodities-on-the-stock-exchange). I know very little about Islamic jurisprudence, but I think the quote refers to short selling and other "deferred transactions" rather than buying stocks outright.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved. @Flux